# can't move a product to a new array which will later be displayed on another page (another component)

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, shopping-cart

each field holds a product, price and the option to click on the "Add to Cart" button, I want that by clicking on the "Add to Cart" button the same product will move to a different array (which will later appear as the list of products purchased on the "Cart" page - another component)
What's not working here? I would be very happy to help! (:

*its really important for me to keep it the simple way like I did, because I want to understand before I move on... also with no routers or hooks! (: thanks!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Cart from './components/Cart.js'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js'

export default class App extends Component {

  state={

    
    flag: false
 
   }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
     
     
     
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:true})}}>Cart</button>
         <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({flag:false})}}>HomePage</button>
         {this.state.flag && (
               <div><Cart/></div>
              )
         }
        {!this.state.flag && (
               <div><HomePage index={i} add={this.addToCart}/></div>
              )
         }
     
       </div>
       
     
       )
     
     }
    }
```

HomePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class HomePage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

        Product: '',
        Price:'',
        tempCartList:'',
        CartList:[{product:'T-shirt', price:'12$'},{product:'Shoes', price:'45$'},{product:'Haircut Machine', price:'60$'}],
        index: props.index
         
    }
}

add=()=>{

    this.props.add(this.state.index)
}

addToCart =(i)=>
 tempCartList = this.state.CartList.filter ((element, index)=>(index != i)); 
 this.setState({CartList:[...tempCartList]})




render() {
    return (
        <div>
            
        <div>Price: </div><div>Product: </div><button onClick={this.add}>+</button>

        


        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Cart.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Cart() {
    return (
        <div>
            This page will show the user all the products that have been added to the cart
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where is `this.addToCart` implementation in `App` components?

Comment: Also there is no `this.delete` in `HomePage`

Comment: Do you mean that if i want to implement this function it must to be in the return of app? I made a lot of mistakes Im sure.. but I dont know how to fix all of the mess.. what is the right way to show the buttons and to implement the function from the HomePage component to the big main one App component ?

Comment: I mean that you have function calls like `this.props.add(this.state.index)` and  `onClick={this.delete}` without implementations behind them.

Comment: I meant `add` instead of `delete`

Comment: I'll keep trying, thanks for now anyways..